# How to push a plot to slack through webhook?

Tags: r, plot, webhooks, slack

I am trying to push a very simple plot to slack to get a sense of how a metric evolves over time. My code seems unnecessarily complicated.
**Is there a proper or better way to do it?**

Here goes my attempt in R, and the current output at the end.

**1. generate dummy values**

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x=seq(-10,10,length.out = 60))
dt$y = sin(dt$x)
plot(dt)
```

Here's what the plot looks like:
[image]

**2. make a "text plot"**

```
# establish the axes values
y_axis = seq(min(dt$y),max(dt$y),length.out = 10)
x_axis = dt$x

# establish to which value of y_axis our y values are the closest 
get_closest_y_axis_point <- function(value){
  closest.value.idx <- which.min(abs(value-y_axis))
  return(y_axis[closest.value.idx])
}

y_values_simplified <- sapply(dt$y,get_closest_y_axis_point)

# make a matrix with only spaces (I found that 2 spaces are as wide as a "o" in slack).
mat = matrix(rep("  ",length(y_axis)*length(x_axis)),nrow = length(y_axis),ncol = length(x_axis))

# replace the spaces by a star wherever there should be a dot on the plot
x_value=0
for (v in 1:length(y_values_simplified)){
  x_value = x_value+1
  y_value = which(rev(y_axis)==y_values_simplified[v])
  mat[y_value,x_value]="*"
}

# collapse the matrix into a long string with line breaks
text.plot <- "*Little Slack Plot*\n"
for (row in 1:dim(mat)[1]){
  new.line=paste(mat[row,],collapse="")
  extra.line = ifelse(row==nrow(mat),"","\n")
  text.plot=paste0(text.plot,new.line,extra.line)
}
```

**3. push the message to slack**

```
webhookurl = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXX"}

slack.post.template = 'curl -X POST -H \'Content-type: application/json\' --data \'{"text":"%s"}\' %s'
command <- sprintf(slack.post.template,text.plot,webhookurl)
system(command)
```

**4. output**
[image: push a plot to slack from R]

Comment: This is a very interesting idea. But your control about how Slack formats the output is very limited, so it will be hard to get a good result on all devices supported by Slack. Why not rather render your plot into an image, upload it to image server like imgur.com and then attach it to your mesage?

Comment: Ouch, you're right, @ErikKalkoken, the output on mobile is not readable at all.. Do you happen to know if the Imgur link trick will display a preview of the image? Otherwise I was thinking of just linking to a Google drive folder..

Comment: yes Slack will automatically show a lower resolution version of your image on devices. You can click it to get the full resolution version.

Comment: that works with any image link btw. imgur is just an example. You can also use Slack for uploading images if you want (its a bit more complicated though). Or any other image cloud service, as long as the image URL is public

Comment: Linking to a Google Drive documents will work, but it required the Slack workspace to have the Google Drive app installed. And if you only have an image file its a bit overkill in my opinion

Comment: Thanks for all these answers, @ErikKalkoken! The plots I am trying to share are not public, but I already have the Gdrive integration. Pushing the image link manually does show a preview, but not pushing it through webhooks, as far as I can see. I need to investigate a bit more this option..

Comment: hmm. I thought that Slack would unfurl the URL when sent over webhooks, but I am not 100% sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a file via the [Slack API](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload). I'd pursue that, as it skips step 2 entirely.

That means you can't upload via a webhook, but you could have the webhook fire off a message to another component and then have that component post to Slack via the [message API](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage).